# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' in c#

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm Creating login form using c#. when I login I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

```
using (var db = new StageCraftEntities())
{
    var isValidUsert = db.Users.Where(i => i.UserName == this.txtUserName.Text.ToString() && i.Password == this.txtPassword.Text.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();


    var isValidUser = from User in db.Users
                      where User.UserName.Equals(this.txtUserName.Text.Trim().ToString())
                      && User.Password.Equals(this.txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToString())
                      select User;

    if(true) 
    {
        Dashboard dashboard = new Dashboard(isValidUsert);
        dashboard.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: do the trimming outiside the linq query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exactly what it says, it can't translate ToString into a valid SQL expression.

Get the username and password strings first.

```
var username = this.txtUserName.Text.ToString();
var password = this.txtPassword.Text.ToString();
```

Then use these in your LINQ:

```
var isValidUsert = db.Users
                     .Where(i => i.UserName == username  && i.Password == password )
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it to variables and check for equality

```
var username = this.txtUserName.Text.Trim().ToString();
var password = this.txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToString();

var isValidUser = from User in db.Users
                              where User.UserName == username
                              && User.Password == password
                              select User;
```